# Representatives of districts that are 50 to 65 percent Hispanic by party?

Tags: united-states, congress, house-of-representatives, statistics, demographics

I was thinking about congressional districts. I found that there was one type of majority-minority district that could be plausibly represented by a Republican. These are districts between 50 and 65 percent Hispanic. These are outside of Florida.

This may not work every time. For example Will Hurd's district is 68% Hispanic. It is a slight outlier but it falls within the general trend.

What are the representatives of 50-65% Hispanic districts in the House and what is their party affiliation. Please exclude FL.

Comment: Can you explain why you chose the range 50-65% Hispanic as being plausibly representable by a Republican?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 16 Congressional districts in which the population is between 50 and 65 percent Hispanic, according to the the [American Community Survey](https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs) (2018). Seven are located in California, two each in New Mexico, New York, Texas, and Arizona, and one in New Jersey.

Only one of these, Texas' 27th District, is represented in the 116th Congress by a Republican, and only two lean Republican with respect to Cook PVI, the other aside from TX-27 (R+13) being New Mexico's 1st District (R+5).

The details of the other districts are below.

```
State,District,Total Pop,Hispanic Pop,Hispanic (%),Rep Party,CPVI
New Mexico,1,697064,350078,50.22,D,R+5
New York,14,706440,356722,50.50,D,D+29
Texas,27,739719,396568,53.61,R,R+13
California,20,739352,400149,54.12,D,D+23
California,31,751527,408571,54.37,D,D+8
New York,13,795633,438038,55.06,D,D+43
New Jersey,8,764837,424366,55.48,D,D+27
New Mexico,2,700113,390187,55.73,D,D+7
California,34,748812,454579,60.71,D,D+35
California,38,716331,439296,61.33,D,D+17
California,16,749967,460662,61.42,D,D+9
Texas,35,818369,505374,61.75,D,D+15
California,41,775626,485439,62.59,D,D+12
California,32,716199,449372,62.74,D,D+17
Arizona,3,798359,506933,63.50,D,D+13
Arizona,7,854749,548361,64.15,D,D+23
```